# Login does not persist across browsers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I am having an issue with my ASP MVC application. When I Log in in IE and open the site with firefox I find my self not logged in. I can't find where is the problem.

Here is how I log in

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(ContactFound.ContaLogin, model.RememberMe);
  if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
  {
     return Redirect(returnUrl);
  }
  else
  {
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
  }
```

Is there a roblem with this code ?

Thanks.

Comment: I just logged into facebook in chrome and it required me to login when I tried in IE.

Comment: Yes you're right, I don't know happened earlier when I logged out from IE, I found my self logged out from firefox. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies (which .NET authentication relies on) will not be available between browsers, so what you're observing is the expected behavior.

If you are dedicated to having the login persist between browsers, you can enable `cookie-less` authentication in the web.config and then the token will be in the URL.  You can paste the URL into a different browser and you'll still be logged in.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx.  However, this is not recommended: http://forums.asp.net/p/1517391/3634908.aspx